# Mozambique visa on arrival for Australian citizen

Tags: tourist-visas, australian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, mozambique

Can you get a visa on arrival for Mozambique as an Australian citizen?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the country"?

Comment: In general you can't get a visa for most countries when you are already in that country. I'm not sure if there are any exceptions.

Comment: If this is actually a question about visas on arrival I'll reverse my close vote.

Answer (score 3):

[***If*** the Wikipedia article is accurate and up-to-date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Mozambique),

> Citizens of all countries **without** a Mozambique embassy can obtain a visa on arrival if they have documentation to prove they are traveling for leisure purposes (return ticket, accommodation confirmation or invitation letter).[[5]](http://www.tourismupdate.co.za/NewsDetails.aspx?newsId=73493) This visa is valid for 30 days, and is extendable up to 60 days.

It seems that though Australia does have an embassy in Maputo, Mozambique does not have an embassy in Australia. This means you should be able to get a visa on arrival if your documentation is in order as per above.

But if I were you I would contact the relevant authorities in Mozambique by email to very this before going ahead too far with your planning. **In fact**, mts has found a source which claims that [you might not get the visa on arrival](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78868/mozambique-visa-on-arrival-for-australian-citizen/78875#comment177055_78875) despite the policy!

Comment: From [Smarttraveller.gov.au](http://smartraveller.gov.au/Countries/africa/east/Pages/mozambique.aspx#) "Mozambican visas can be arranged prior to travelling through the nearest Embassy or Consulate of Mozambique. There have been reports of travellers having difficulties obtaining visas on arrival. "

Comment: The rumour that Mozambique has stopped issuing visas on arrival to nationals of countries with an embassy was originally made by the US embassy in Maputo.

However, I asked IATA, the ones behind the Timatic database used by Airlines, to check with their sources. They did and made no changes.

Their info states it's still possible to obtain a visa on arrival regardless of your nationality.

Comment: @Crazydre: Even better! Would you like to try editing the Wikipedia article since it seems to wrong? If they want a reference you can tell them that the current article seems to contain an unreferenced rumour. It might also be worth editing Wikivoyage where there is a lot less fightback (-: In fact the link I got from Wikipedia is now broken anyway.